# python watchdog observer not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-watchdog

I  this script not working on vagrant which have Ubuntu 16.04

This code working fine on mac

```python
 import sys
 import time
 import logging
 from watchdog.observers import Observer
 from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

 if __name__ == "__main__":
 logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                  format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                  datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
  event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
  observer = Observer()
  observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
  observer.start()
  try:
      while True:
        time.sleep(1)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
      observer.stop()
      observer.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

its solved, watchdog event not firing because I have added new file from outside of vagrant :)